# Best practice creating a key/value map dev/prod node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a Node.js app, APP-A, that communicates with another C# app, APP-B, using APP-B's API. APP-B has a RESTful API that returns JSON. Other than a few standard fields e.g., name, description, APP-B's keys are defined when the user creates the field in the system. The resulting JSON looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "An example name",
  "description": "Description for the example",
  "cust_fields": {
    "cust_123": "Joe Bloggs",
    "cust_124": "Essex"
  }
}
```

I have two instances of APP-B, a dev and prod environment, which are separate installations. As a result, the JSON from the prod environment is as above, and the JSON from the dev environment looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "An example name",
  "description": "Description for the example",
  "cust_fields": {
    "cust_782": "Joe Bloggs",
    "cust_793": "Essex"
  }
}
```

This is dealt with in APP-A (the Node.js app) by having a JSON map like this:

```
{
  "name": "name",
  "description": "description",
  "cust_fields": {
    "full_name": "cust_123",
    "city": "cust_124"
  }
}
```

Which is loaded like this:

```
var map;
switch(env) {
  case 'dev':
    map = require('../env/dev/map.json');
    break;
  case 'prod':
    map = require('../env/prod/map.json');
    break;
};

module.exports = {
  name: map.name,
  description: map.description,
  cust_fields: {
    full_name: map.cust_fields.full_name,
    city: map.cust_fields.city,
  }
}
```

So I am wondering, is there is a better way of dealing with this? I don't see a way around having to create some kind of manual relationship between the key names across prod and dev, as there is no way to find out what field corresponds to what, but it seems like a lot of work.

Thanks for reading.

**Update:**

I have created a jsFiddle to better illustrate my question: http://jsfiddle.net/7k9k03o6.

Comment: I'd agree, maintaining this manually is not a long term solution. So every user has a custom field name that is specific to them? And you're trying to map them to the same field on the server? If they are really not unique, perhaps just use an enum for field generation, so they can pick custom fields out of a list? Or if they are always the same, just define the fields for every user and some fields will be empty if they don't choose to fill them? A little more explanation of what you're trying to do would be good - maybe it is a more simple use case than what is set up right now.

Comment: I have created a jsFiddle to better illustrate my question: https://jsfiddle.net/7k9k03o6/. I guess the point really is dealing with changing keys across two environments.

Comment: Why are you using different field names for different environments? That seems like a big headache - for what reason are you doing that?

Comment: The system with changing field names is not something I have control over. It is a forms and workflow system which allows users to build their own forms and add their own fields. When a user adds a new field in their system, APP-B, and wants it to appear in the Node.js system, APP-A, this is the approach that is being used to do that. Yes, it is a massive headache - hence my question. There has to be a better way.

Answer (score 0):

If the mapping is unavoidable and everything is done manually right now, the next best progression would be to automate the building of those lookup maps, through some persistent storage, i.e. a database.

The general flow would be:

1. When APP-B creates a new form, that field information is stored in the database with all the identifying information. You *could* store production and dev data in the same db (as a flag) but likely they would just be different databases. Structure might be like `customerId, formId, fieldName, fieldMapping, fieldValue, isProduction` --> `123, 2, 'cust_124', 'city', 'Essex', true`
2. When APP-A needs a field listing, it queries the DB for the relevant field lists."Find mapping customer X for form Y in production" --> `WHERE custId = 123 AND formId = 2 AND isProduction = true` would yield a list of fields and their mapping values (which you would post process/reduce into the mapping you need).

This automated process will leave less work for you manually. You shouldn't accidentally miss or forget a mapping from the hand generated file.

This will add a tiny bit of work to the server processing, as you'll need the field mapping from the DB every time a request is processed. (You could back off a bit and do one big query each time a customer is loaded, or further back is each time the server starts . . . depends how dynamic these custom fields are). Plus you would have to map DB results into a usable listing for your purposes.

Depending how many customers and custom forms you are monitoring, an automated process for that will save you a lot of time and avoid a lot of mistakes of all things hand generated.